# Definition of Existence of Identity in a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a binary operation structure to be a group in a Set, i.e., $G = \langle*,S\rangle$

One must have an identity $e$ in $G$ s.t. $a*e = e*a =a \ \forall a \in G$.

But does it mean that e is one element which is applied to all element in $G$ or just it's okay for $e$ to specifically exist for each $a$ in $G$, e.g., if $(e_0, a_0), (e_1, a_1)\cdots (e_n, a_n)$ where $e_i$'s are different and meeting the criterion $e_i * a_i = a_i * e_i = a_i$ ?

Comment: The definition should be "there exists $e$ such that for all $a$ $a*e=e*a=a$". By putting "there exists $e$ at the beginning of the sentence and "for all $a$" at the end, the writer has left room for t misunderstanding "for all $a$ there exists $e$ such that $a*e=e*a=a$".That's one reason why, in formal logic, one always writes the quantifiers before the statement they quantify, not one quantifier before and the other after, as here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to write this out in quantifiers:

$$\exists e \in G: \forall g \in G: ge =g = eg$$

In other words, the existential quantifier comes for the universal quantifier, and hence it means that the element $e$ has to work for every group element.

In particular, it follows that this element $e$ is unique so the answer to your question is no: we can't have different identities for different elements. Every element has the same identity.

Comment: Is there any good notation to use for "for each" which is distinguished from "for all" noatation ?

Comment: For each and for all mean the same thing.

Comment: it looks for each means $\{a_0\}, \{a_1\}, \{a_2\} ..\forall a_i's \in A$ but for all means $\{a_o, a_1, a_2...\}$ I think.

Comment: No there is no distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1):

The identity should work for all elements and it is unique.

That means if $e_1$ and $e_2$  are identities then $e_1=e_2$

Just like for the group of integers under addition, there is only one $0$ which works for all integers.

Answer (score 0):

$e$ is supposed to be one element that serves as the identity for the entire group.

Comment: so the meaning of 'for all' and 'for each' is different in logic

Comment: @delinco no. The identity is: **there exists** $e\in G$ such that $ae=ea=a$ **for all** $a\in G$. The "for all" comes after the "there exists", so the one $e$ works for all elements of $G$. Note, the definition does not imply uniqueness of $e$, however one can show that $e$ is indeed unique.

Answer (score -1):

It is just one $e$ that satisfies this criterion. Identity doesn't have to specifically exist for each and every element. 
Try proving the theorem:the identity element in a group is unique
Hint: assume it there are two identities and go on to show that they both are the same.